# Can I use Font-Awesome in Froala without changing to svg

Tags: svg, font-family, froala

I want to use Font-Awesome in my project, during using Froala's page maker, it's convert every Font-Awesome to SVG format.

How could I stop the converting, because it's goes wrong.